# Why does Inspec return "expected [] to include" when checking for aws_elbs ports?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, inspec

This is an Inspec control that checks for the VPC-Id, Ports, Subnets and AZs for a specific Network Loadbalancer:

```
control 'Loadbalancer Config' do
  title 'Checks for correct configuration of LBs'
  describe aws_elbs.where(arn: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:123456789:loadbalancer/app/web-app-alb/1d234567890d') do
    its('vpc_ids') { should include 'vpc-a12345678' }
    its('subnet_ids') { should include 'subnet-12345678' }
    its('internal_ports') { should include 443 }
    its('availability_zones') { should include 'eu-central-1a' }
  end
end
```

When executing, the tests fail and I get

> expected [] to include "vpc-a12345678"
>
> expected [] to include 443
>
> expected [] to include "subnet-12345678"
>
> expected [] to include "eu-central-1a"

I double checked the ARN of the Loadbalancer but I always get this empty array of results.

Answer (score 0):

I am now pretty sure that this happens because **Inspec does not support Network Load Balancers**. 
Will leave this here in case someone has the same issue.